# Using SASS's @for for multiple selectors and 1 body

Tags: css, sass

Let's say I want to generate the following `CSS` using `SCSS`:

```
.selector-1,
.selector-2,
.selector-3,
.selector-4,
.selector-5 {
    color: blue;
}
```

How would you write that in `SCSS`? Using this `@for` loop

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .selector-{$i} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

would naturally generate

```
.selector-1 {
    color: blue;
}
.selector-2 {
    color: blue;
}
.selector-3 {
    color: blue;
}
.selector-4 {
    color: blue;
}
.selector-5 {
    color: blue;
}
```

which would be too much code.

Comment: It is in fact a duplicate, despite heavy googling, I did not find the other question.

Comment: can you hardcode like this?

$i: 1;
.selector-#{$i}, .selector-#{$i+1}, .selector-#{$i+2}, .selector-#{$i+3}, .selector-#{$i+4}, .selector-#{$i+5} {
    color: blue;
}

Comment: No, cos what would be the point of using a loop? And I am using a loop cos I am doing this 24 times.